# NHibernate 2.1 Example?

Tags: c#, vb.net, nhibernate

I am having problems finding an example project that uses NHibernate 2.1.0.  Anyone know of some that are out there, or even open source projects that use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Sharp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) and the demo project that comes with it uses NHibernate 2.1 - also one of the newer versions of Fluent-NHibernate (which I highly recommend if you don't want to get lost in xml-mapping hell).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using NHibernate 2.1 in my current project at work.

But, why do you need an example project that uses NH2.1 ?  Most of the example projects that show you how to use NH, are very limited.
I mean; those projects are so simple that the new things that have been introduced in NH2.1 are possibly not used.

Comment: Interesting... I guess I don't need an example that uses 2.1, I just thought if I am going to start I might as well use the newest version, and some of the samples I found used code that did not work with the 2.1 libraries, like the 'your first nhibernate based application'.  I used that one first and found the schemaexport.execute call to be different.  What version of nHibernate are most people using and why?